# Reset previous chosen shipping method in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

Currently, I am clearing the default shipping selection method using this filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', '__return_false', 99);
```

However, this only clears it during the initial session of the customer. Once the customer chooses an option even once, it remembers the selection for the future.

I am trying to get the checkout to force the customer to pick a shipping option every time they visit the checkout even in the same session. Is it possible to run this filter every time the checkout page is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the last chosen shipping method using in checkout page (for logged in customers):

```
 delete_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_method' );
```

And also remove the chosen shipping method from session data:

```
WC()->session->__unset( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
```

In a hooked function like:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'reset_previous_chosen_shipping_method' );
function reset_previous_chosen_shipping_method() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && is_user_logged_in() 
    && get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_method', true ) ) {
        delete_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_method' );
        WC()->session->__unset( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    }
}
```

---

Or you can also set a default shipping method for everybody in checkout page:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'reset_previous_chosen_shipping_method' );
function reset_previous_chosen_shipping_method() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', array('flat_rate:14') );
    }
}
```

To find out the shipping methods rate Ids to be used, you can inspect the shipping method radio buttons in cart or checkout pages, with your browser inspector like:

[image]

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Hi Loic, thanks for the reply. I've just tried inserting the hook but it hasn't changed anything. I am logged in as a user(admin). The site im working on is this: https://bossairsuspension.co.nz/checkout/

Comment: @DonovanRucastle, For me it works… I have updated my answer with a 2nd alternative. Try that.

Comment: I really do appreciate your continued help! Your second piece of code works but I am trying to set it that no shipping methods are selected when the page loads. I have your first piece of code running on the site currently but it doesn't unselect the shipping option upon page reload. Is there any way to clear all details on the checkout page whenever someone reloads the page? Almost like not caching the whole checkout page not just the shipping method.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help thus far! It does correctly clear the selected options when emptying the cart but not just on a page refresh. I think this is a good starting point though!

Comment: I am using you solution and works good. The problem i am having on my ajax checkout, it that i am using "validation-required" class property on shipping methods and are not getting updated to "woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field". Is this a woo bug or since this is not supported we have to handle it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution, it might be a bit hacky.
Just unsets currently selected shipping method and then checks if it's present while validating the checkout.

```
add_action(
    'woocommerce_before_checkout_form',
    'reset_previous_chosen_shipping_method'
);
function reset_previous_chosen_shipping_method()
{
    if (is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) {
        unset(WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods);
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate', 10, 2);
function validate($data, $errors)
{
    if (!$data['shipping_method']) {
        $errors->add('validation', __('Please select shipping method'));
    }
}
```